# Creating a number line with an arrow underneath to represent the distance

Tags: graphics, underbrace

I am taking an Elementary Real Analysis class and am typing my lecture notes in LaTex. I was wondering if anyone knew how to create this number line that represents the distance between two integers.  I would like the points labeled "m" and "n". Also, I would like an arrow underneath the points representing the distance between the two points is greater than or equal to one. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you try so far? the image is relative simple to draw with help of selected package, like `tikz`, `pstrick`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

%---------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (9,0);

        \draw (0,0) -- (10,0) ;
        \path node[mark size=3pt,color=red] at (A) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}} node at (A) [above=5pt] {$m \in \mathbb{Z}$} node[mark size=3pt,color=red] at (B) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}} node at (B) [above=5pt] {$n \in \mathbb{Z}$};
        \draw[latex-latex] ([yshift=-0.5cm]A) -- node[below] {Distance $\ge 1$}([yshift=-0.5cm]B) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]